# onClick incorrectly being Registered

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick

I tried to implement an onClick method to my card recyclerView. When I click the card nothing happens but when I click the gap between the cards the intended action is performed. This was confirmed when as I tested this by increasing the spacing between the cards. What did I do wrong and how do I change my code to fix this problem?

This is the Adapter

```
public class JobListRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JobListRecyclerAdapter.jobViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<JobClass> jobClassList;
    private static OnItemClickListener clickListener;


    public JobListRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<JobClass> rList) {
        this.jobClassList = rList;

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(jobClassList == null){return 0;}
        return jobClassList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public jobViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.job_list_card, viewGroup, false);
        return new jobViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(jobViewHolder jobViewHolder, int position) {
        JobClass ci = jobClassList.get(position);
        jobViewHolder.jName.setText("Name: "+ci.getmJobNum());
        jobViewHolder.jDate.setText("Quantity: "+ci.getmJobDate());
    }

    public void setClickListener(OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public static class jobViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        protected TextView jName;
        protected TextView jDate;;

        public jobViewHolder(View j) {
            super(j);

            jName =  (TextView) j.findViewById(R.id.job_name);
            jDate = (TextView)  j.findViewById(R.id.job_due_date);
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.job_card_layout).setOnClickListener(this); // bind the listener

        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (clickListener != null) {clickListener.onClick(view, getLayoutPosition());}

        }
    }

    }
```

This is the Activity

```
public class JobList extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    public JobList() {
    }
    public static JobList newInstance() {
        JobList fragment = new JobList();

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_job_list, container, false);
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.job_list_recycler_view);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        final ArrayList<JobClass> joblistclass = new ArrayList<>();
        /*
        // Create a new Adapter
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);
            */

        // Get a reference to the todoItems child items it the database
        //String userPath = ((GlobalData) getActivity().getApplication()).getUserPath() +"JOBS";
        //final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(userPath);
        // final DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("USERS/04950F4AE53F80/JOBS");
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference jobsRef = rootRef
                .child("USERS")
                .child("04950F4AE53F80")
                .child("JOBS");
        // Assign a listener to detect changes to the child items
        // of the database reference.
        // myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String jobno = ds.child("JOBOVERVIEW").child("jobNum").getValue(String.class);
                    JobClass jblst = ds.child("JOBOVERVIEW").getValue(JobClass.class);
                    joblistclass.add(jblst);

                    ((GlobalData) getContext().getApplicationContext()).saveJobNum(jobno);
                }

                final JobListRecyclerAdapter adapterb = new JobListRecyclerAdapter(joblistclass);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterb);
                adapterb.setClickListener(JobList.this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };
        jobsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

        ///to send to next page
        Button nextPage = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addNewJob);

        // Capture button clicks
        nextPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getContext(), JobForm.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }


@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    ArrayList<String> nameArray = ((GlobalData) getActivity().getApplication()).getJobNums();
    String name = nameArray.get(position);
    ((GlobalData) getActivity().getApplication()).setJobId(name);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), name,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Card View XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:id="@+id/job_card_layout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:clickable="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/job_linear_layout"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/job_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/job_due_date"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/job_name"
            android:clickable="true"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: The XML can be provided if needed.

Comment: Please add job_list_card xml

Comment: xml added @nomag

Comment: Try j.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/job_card_layout"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
  app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/job_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_due_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/job_name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: android:clickable="true" has to be removed from your xml file.
Also, use

```
j.setOnClickListener(this);
```

instead of

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have itemView field in your adapter or viewHolder as I can see. Maybe jobViewHolder should look like this:

```
        jName =  (TextView) j.findViewById(R.id.job_name);
        jDate = (TextView)  j.findViewById(R.id.job_due_date);
        j.findViewById(R.id.job_card_layout).setOnClickListener(this); // bind the listener
```

Comment: I Tried this but it is still doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your child view is placed at foreground and take all interactive from user. Let try this code in your child view xml.

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

Comment: does this go in the linear layout of the card or in the cardview section.

Comment: @savi put it in linear layout and 2 textview inside.

Answer (score 0):

Update **jobViewHolder** class

Change following line

```
itemView.findViewById(R.id.job_card_layout).setOnClickListener(this); // bind the listener
```

to

```
j.findViewById(R.id.job_card_layout).setOnClickListener(this); // bind the listener
```

**OR**

```
j.setOnClickListener(this); // bind the listener
```

**NOTE**: If this doesn't work then you are referring wrong id i.e. job_card_layout

**Updated JobViewHolder.java**

```
public static class jobViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected TextView jName;
    protected TextView jDate;;

    public jobViewHolder(View j) {
        super(j);

        jName =  (TextView) j.findViewById(R.id.job_name);
        jDate = (TextView)  j.findViewById(R.id.job_due_date);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this); // bind the listener

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (clickListener != null) {clickListener.onClick(view, getLayoutPosition());}

    }
}
```